# Entity list by parent entity and dotted paths

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, breeze, devforce

I'm using Angular 5 + Breeze JS + breeze-bridge2-angular.

Suppose we have a `Company` entity that have multiple navigation properties of type `Address` and `Address` entity type, in its own turn, has some navigation properties like `Country`, etc:

```
import { Entity } from "breeze-client"; // From https://www.npmjs.com/package/breeze-client package 

export class Company implements Entity {
    billingAddress: Address;
    shippingAddress: Address;
}

export class Address implements Entity {
    country1: Country;
    country2: Country;
}

export class Country implements Entity {
    ...
}
```

All entities have been already queried into `EntityMnager`, no need to query anything from server.

**How to implement a method (probably using some Breeze JS API I'm missing so far)** taking a parent `Company` entity and a `string[]` of dotted property paths and returns a flat `Entity[]` list containing parent entity and all child entities located by using those dotted paths?

The dotted paths are just the same as we use with `expand()` method in Breeze queries (see **Dotted expand paths** [here](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/navigation-properties.html)), i.e.:

```
const company: Company = ...; // Query Company and its children into EntityManager
const paths: string[] = [
    "billingAddress",
    "shippingAddress",
    "billingAddress.country1",
    "billingAddress.country2"];

getEntitiesFlat(entity: Entity, paths: string[]): Entity[] {
    // Not sure how to implement getChildren() method below
    const childEntities: Entity[] = this.getChildren(entity, paths);

    return [entity].concat(childEntities);
}
```

By the way, I'm trying to implement deletion of parent entity and its **specific** child entities and the above is the cleanest way I've came up so far inspired by DevForce framework. Better ideas are extremely welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not *really* sure what you're looking for. Assuming you're taking `path` and mapping those paths against the `entity` object... I came up with:

```
function getByPath(entity: any, path: string) {
  if (!entity) return undefined

  const parts = path.split(".")

  if (parts.length === 1) {
    return entity[path]
  }

  return getByPath(entity[parts[0]], parts.slice(1).join("."))
}
```

use like

```
const paths = ["a", "a.b.c", "a.b.d", "d", "c", "d.c"]
const entity = {
  a: { b: { c: 1 } },
  b: 1,
  c: 2
}

paths.map(path => getByPath(entity, path)) // [ { b: { c: 1 } }, 1, undefined, undefined, 2, undefined ]
```

edit: if you're using `lodash` already, just use [`lodash#get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#get)

Comment: Nice idea, thank you! If nobody comes up with a solution using some Breeze JS API instead of parsing paths manually, I'll accept your implementation.

Comment: sorry! I missed that part of your comment! I'm not familiar with Breeze.

Comment: No, you excuse me for that - I added that part after your response, since I've obviously failed to explain exactly what I'm after :)